# Math Formula for PHP script

Tags: math, logic

I'm not to good at math, and I need to write a script that says, "Every 3rd level, this event will trigger" (level being a character level in a game).

Could anybody help me out with this? Thanks! You don't have to convert it to code, I can work with just the formula (or however it's most easily explained!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the modulo operator, which returns the remainder after division:

```
if (level % 3 == 0) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Would that work consistently with any number? That just says if this number is cleanly dividable by 3, do this.

Comment: Yes, that will work consistently. The condition will be true for 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, ...

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understand correctly, you can do:

```
If (level % 3 == 0) {
    Do your thing
}
```